# Hide border using mpandroidchart 2.0.7

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) 2.0.7. How can I hide the border ? In the version 1.7.4, the method setDrawBorder(boolean) was available, it is not the case anymore :(

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Version 3.0.0 out now.

You can call

- `chart.setDrawBorders(boolean)` to enable / disable drawing the border
- `yaxis.setDrawAxisLine(boolean)` to enable / disable the lines drawn alongside the y-axis, same goes for the x-axis

If you set everything to false, no more borders should be drawn.